# Is it possible to get session values from action to another in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to get the values of the session in mvc4 application from the action. For example
Person to action Machine by getting the current person ID/Name ?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking....

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is asking. You can access the Session from anywhere in your MVC code, so your Person and Machine action methods can call `Session["WhateverYourKeyIs"]` to obtain data from the session. Is this the type of thing you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use and access `Session` as usual in a MVC application.
But I believe you are looking for a method to pass values from one action result to another,
 You can check [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can always get session values across different action methods like:

```
string value=Session["Name"].ToString();
```

Or you can use TempData to persist value across methods:

```
var value= TempData["key"];
TempData.Keep();
```